# Adding fonts to assets pipeline rails 4.2.x

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts

I'm trying to deploy my app on heroku but still fonts are not loading, this is my relevant font sass :

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0')
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format("embedded-opentype"), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format("woff2"), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format("woff"), url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format("truetype"), url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format("svg")
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

And I have these fonts mentioned above here at `app/assets/fonts`. Then I have assets initializer :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

What can I do to address this issue, this seems to be a common issue, but none of the common solution work, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to use `asset-url` instead of `url`? It is what is working for us.

Comment: @EgonWilzer can you please make that an answer, works awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `url` you should use `asset-url` in sass.

See here for more information: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#user-content-asset-helpers

So this should work:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome'
  src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0')
  src: asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format("embedded-opentype"), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format("woff2"), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format("woff"), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format("truetype"), asset-url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format("svg")
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your assets are precompiled you should use Rails' `asset_path` helper.  Change your scss file to scss.erb and modify your `@font-face` block to something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0' %>);
  src: url(<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0' %>) format('embedded-opentype'),
  /* etc... */
}
```